# I have table called orders and in that table I have 3 columns and order_no, start_date, end_date

Tags: postgresql

I want to write a query to select the records where today's date (sysdate) is in between the start_date  and end_date
and also if the end_date is not present (Null) then I have to add sysdate+1 which means(today is 07-01-2022 so it should become 8-01-2022) and show it in output

Records present in the table :

**(1,'01-01-2022','09-01-2022'),
(2,'02-01-2022',null ),
(3,'31-12-2022','01-01-2022')**

Thanks

Comment: Please post a concise and complete example, include table DDL and sample data INSERT statements as single, runnable T-SQL script. Also include the sample output.

Comment: Table:  create table orders(order_id int,
        start_date date,
     end_date date)
Data in table: insert into orders (order_id,start_date,end_date)
   values (1,'01-01-2022','09-01-2022'),
       (2,'02-01-2022',null ),
       (3,'31-12-2022','01-01-2022')
i want to output the records where sysdate is in between the start_date and end_date

Comment: If there is no end_date then it  should add one day to today's date and show that also as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN start_date AND COALESCE(end_date, CURRENT_DATE + 1)
```

Few additional points on the script,
CURRENT_DATE would give you the system date and
COALESCE will check for null in 'end_date' and use CURRENT_DATE + 1

Comment: it helped thanks, is there any way to change the end_date column from null to   CURRENT_DATE + 1

Comment: @Dinesh: `coalesce(end_date, current_date + 1)`